# How to display complete request and response on Test Result analyzer results?

Tags: jenkins, soap, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins SoapUI project. I use Test result analyzer to view the results:

[image]

For any failed test, when you click on the Failed status link, you are displayed with the test failure with the message:

[image]

But we are not displayed with the actual request and response.

Is there a way I could display the actual request and response on the test step failure? This is an improvement I am trying to add to my project.

Comment: it's kind of hard to understand without all the details but maybe you should try archiving the entire folder since it seems some files are missing and haven't been archived. I hope I understood the question correctly

Comment: @eranmeiri I am currently archiving the entire folder which has all the test steps with detailed request response. But my question is to have the request response displayed on clicking the Failed link.

Comment: is it in HTML format ? usually if a sub link in HTML report is not working it means it's either not archived or not published correctly